# Cannot use string literals for className in react CSS imports?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, styling, classname

This is the `style.css` file:

```
.cake {
  color: red;
}
```

This is `index.js`:

**Fails:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import './style.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="cake">Hello!</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

The CSS styling fails to render and the text is just black in browser.

However, this does work:

**Succeeds:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import styles from './style.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.cake}>Hello!!</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

This is the relevant section of `webpack.config.js`:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

I would like to have the option of using the string literal version, and I'm a bit perplexed that many people online seem to have it available. Is there some webpack config change I can apply? Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: No I spun up my own package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the magic:

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Actually you've enabled css-modules, which in my opinion are really great to have. You can read more about css-modules [here](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).